# Public datasets that show "cyclical" behavior

Tags: dataset

I am looking for any publicly available dataset that has a "cyclical" structure to it, in the sense that if I plot the data in a certain way, a loop becomes visible.  A good example of this would be the [Lotka-Volterra predator-prey model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations), which has a very pronounced cycle, shown below.  Are there any other good examples that demonstrate this?

[image: Predator-prey picture]

Comment: Welcome to DS SE! I posted an answer that should help you find relevant datasets, but any dataset requests would be better received on the Open Data SE site: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/. The reason I answered this one was because I thought I could give more information (particular search terms) than simply providing a link to a dataset

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

The search term you are looking for is **[limit cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle)**. You can find some examples (legged-locomotion, digital control systems, etc.) here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/limit-cycle.